# NestJs Is not injecting value in jest unit test

Tags: unit-testing, nestjs

I cant figure out why nestjs is not injecting value into my contstructor

Controller

```
export class HealthCheckController {
  constructor(@Inject('HealthCheckService') private healthCheckService: HealthCheckService, private appLogger: AppLogger) {
  }
```

Then my test

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [HealthCheckController],
      providers: [
        AppLoggerNope.getProvider(),
       { provide: 'HealthCheckService', useClass: HealthCheckService },
      ],
    })
      .compile();
    controller = await module.resolve<HealthCheckController>(HealthCheckController);
    const logger = await module.resolve<AppLogger>(AppLogger);
    service = await module.resolve<HealthCheckService>('HealthCheckService');
  });
```

NopeLogger

```
export class AppLoggerNope {
  static getProvider() {
    return {
      provide: AppLogger,
      useValue: {}
    }
  }
}
```

So if I debug my test I can see that instance of service is supplied but logger is null.

Now what is interesting if I comment appLogger in provider controller will be created but it will fail  `await module.resolve<AppLogger>(AppLogger);`

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `app.resolve` over `app.get`? Are you using REQUEST scoped providers?

Comment: originally there were get, and i just tried to see if it works with resolve as i thought it would be request scoped...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to explicitly define an injection token for the `HealthCheckService` with `@Inject`, Nest will resolve it for you. You also don't need to use `module.resolve` unless you're using [request-scoped providers](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes). I've also pulled out the provider from your `AppLoggerNope` static method for simplicity. If this is working, then you can start to get fancy and move those values elsewhere.

Controller:

```
export class HealthCheckController {
  constructor(private healthCheckService: HealthCheckService, private appLogger: AppLogger) { }
```

Test file:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [HealthCheckController],
      providers: [
        { provide: AppLogger, useValue: {} },
       HealthCheckService,
      ],
    })
      .compile();
    controller = module.get<HealthCheckController>(HealthCheckController);
    const logger = module.get<AppLogger>(AppLogger);
    service = module.get<HealthCheckService>(HealthCheckService);
  });
```

Note that the `HealthCheckService` is supplied directly as a provider in the testing module. Unless you need to mock something or stub out some kind of functionality, you can directly use it as a provider in your testing module. If you needed to be able to assert that some method within `HealthCheckService` was called in a test, you may want to do something like this:

```
    const mockedHealthCheck = { someMethod: jest.fn() };
    module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [HealthCheckController],
      providers: [
        { provide: AppLogger, useValue: {} },
        { provide: HealthCheckService, useValue: mockedHealthCheck,
      ],
    })
      .compile();
```

Then in your test you can assert `expect(mockedHealthCheck.someMethod).toBeCalled()`.

Comment: I need to use inject as my HealthCheckService is interface. Even more i tried to remove this injection still does not work